# Xcode 7 iOS emulated app cannot find network

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode7

My iOS app is not detecting a network connection when I run it in the simulator in Xcode. The Simulator can connect otherwise, if I open it directly, I can load web pages in Safari, but I can't get the app to detect a connection.

Comment: Sometimes Simulator does not detect the network, its known issue. Reboot your machine, it should work.

Comment: I've rebooted several times, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Some time Internet will not connected with the Simulatore . 
Just Click on

```
Simulatore -> Reset content and setting
```

And reset it , and make some internet is connected with your system .

May be it helps you or feel free?

Comment: just try with restart your system .

Comment: And also check into the setting of the simulatore

Comment: Restarting didn't help either.